# Why does Vec::iter_mut not show up in the documentation index of std::vec::Vec?

Tags: rust, rustdoc

In https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.iter,

I can only find `iter` in the index sidebar to the left of the page. However, `iter_mut` could not be found.

Could anyone explain if it's intentional, or a bug?

This is inconvenient because search through text is hard when browsing from phone. I was scrolling through the index and could not find `iter_mut`.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sidebar only shows methods that use the `Deref` implementation, not those that use the `DerefMut` implementation. As such, the sidebar only shows non-mutable slice methods. This is a [known bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/60326). A fix has been merged and can be seen in [the documentation for the beta release](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/vec/struct.Vec.html). I assume then that the fix will be in next stable release.